# Como adicionar 0 em uma coluna?

Tags: sql-server

Sou iniciante em linguagem SQL e gostaria de uma ajuda para executar uma query.

Preciso de uma nova coluna com os dados: codigo+tamanho+cor (fiz o concatenar e deu certo)

o problema que não consigo resolver é que a cor precisa ter 3 caracteres, porem tem cores que tem um caracter no id e cores que tem 2 caracteres.

preciso que quando tiver 1 caracter no codigo seja adicionado mais 2 zeros.

e quando tiver 2 caracteres no código seja adicionado mais 1 zero.

exemplo:

```
cod.    cod_novo

1       001
2       002
3       003
99      099


    SELECT
        "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Prod_Serv",
        "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Tamanho",
        "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Cor",
        "Prod_Serv"."Codigo",
        "Prod_Serv"."Nome",
        "Cores"."Nome" AS "nome_cor",
        "Tamanhos"."Nome" AS "tamanho",
        "Tamanhos"."Codigo",
        "Cores"."Codigo",
        "Estoque_Atual"."Qtde_Estoque_Atual",
        CONCAT ( "prod_serv"."codigo", "tamanhos"."codigo", '0', "Cores"."codigo"  ) AS GRADE 
    FROM
        "Estoque_Atual"
        INNER JOIN "Prod_Serv" ON "Prod_Serv"."Ordem" = "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Prod_Serv"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "Tamanhos" ON "Tamanhos"."Ordem" = "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Tamanho"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "Cores" ON "Cores"."Ordem" = "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Cor" 
    WHERE
        "Prod_Serv"."Codigo" = '1009'
        AND "Estoque_atual"."Qtde_Estoque_Atual" > 0
    GROUP BY
        "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem",
        "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Prod_Serv",
        "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Tamanho",
        "Estoque_Atual"."Ordem_Cor",
        "Estoque_Atual"."Qtde_Estoque_Atual",
        "Prod_Serv"."Codigo",
        "Prod_Serv"."Nome",
        "Cores"."Nome",
        "Tamanhos"."Nome",
        "Tamanhos"."Codigo",
           "Cores"."Codigo"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer um `replicate` de `'0'` conforme o tamanho (`len`) do valor presente no campo:

```
concat(replicate('0', 3 - len(campo)),campo) as meu_novo_campo
```

---

Com o seu campo, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
concat(replicate('0', 3 - len("Cores"."codigo")),"Cores"."codigo")
```

Juntando com os demais campos:

```
CONCAT ( "prod_serv"."codigo", "tamanhos"."codigo", concat(replicate('0', 3 - len("Cores"."codigo")),"Cores"."codigo") ) AS GRADE
```

---

> Veja um exemplo online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ffa2f/7

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel, funcionou do jeito que eu precisava.